# Lookup multiple values on multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel

I am working in excel 2013. I have a table called data.

```
color   letter   number
red     a        1 
red     b        2 
blue    a        1
blue    a        1
blue    b        1
blue    a        2
blue    a        2
```

I want to look up [number] for all rows where [color]=blue and [letter]=a, so the rows I highlighted above.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data[number],AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(data[#All])/((data[color]="blue")*(data[letter]="a")), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

This code gives me all [number] that are "blue" and "a", and currently returns

```
number
1
1
2
2
```

How do I get it to return this instead:

```
table
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an array formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data[number], MATCH(0, IF(Data[color]="blue", IF(Data[letter]="a", COUNTIF(G$2:G2, Data[number]), 1), 1), 0)), "")
```

[image]

Comment: can you help me walk through the logic of this? so the MATCH() is attempting to find the row number of a line that matches the criteria. Match is trying to find anything less than 0 in the array |||     IF(data[custOrderId2]=$D$1, COUNTIF(data[subKit2],$F$1:F1), 1) |||      Im having trouble figuring out what this array represents

Comment: never mind i figured it out :) this answer works perfectly thank you so much!